# Excluding JUnit tests in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Hey
I have a whole bunch of unit tests. I have placed them into suitable test suites. I would like to be able to click on the root directory and go run JUnit tests to execute all the tests. However, if I do this it runs all the tests AND then runs the testsuites. Therefore running all the tests again.

Is there someway to exclude the testsuites in Eclipse?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you right click on the project directory and `Run As > JUnit test` it's basically the relevant run configuration that is being triggered. Therefore go to `Run > Run Configurations` and on the left panel see exactly what your JUnit configuration is actually doing and configure accordingly.

Comment: I can change the run configuration to only execute tests in a certain folder, and it works if I run it from the Configurations panel. But If I click on the root folder and go run as > JUnit test it goes back to ignoring it.

Comment: I think dimitri is suggesting that you either create a new JUnit run configuration, so you'll instead do a run as -> Run configurations and create a new junit run config. Perhaps create one for unit tests and one for integration. The run-time configs offer test classes and test methods to be used.

Comment: If you want to execute your test config quickly you can either: 1) visit the dropdown next to the Run As button (a circled triangle) where the most recent executions are being shown or 2) keep your Window>Show View>JUnit panel and rerun test or 3) hit Ctrl+F11 to rerun the last run execution.