# Eclipse and Junit, skipover some testcase with some pattern

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

000 unit test in one application. I know in one particular folder, all the tests takes long time, I donot want to test these cases everytime I run unit test. So may I have some property file to indiciate a pattern/folder which test cases shall skip?

I am using mvn. Java 1.6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excluding JUnit tests in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461673/excluding-junit-tests-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Maven Surefire Plugin: Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

To exclude certain tests you can use:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.9</version>
   <configuration>
     <excludes>
       <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
       <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
     </excludes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Alternatively, on the command line, you can explicitly specify which tests you want to run. For example:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestSquare,TestCi*le test
```

Comment: yes, but I want to run in Eclipse window, not command window. In command window, this is already implemented. But in Eclipse, I could not do the same as command window with mvn command.

Comment: how do you run the tests in eclipse?